# Is it possible to list the location of leaked memory in valgrind?

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, valgrind

**This is *not* a duplicate. Please see below.**

Running valgrind with the options `--track-origins=yes --leak-check=full --leak-resolution=high` gives a very nice report of what *kind* of memory block(s) are definitely lost, *which functions* allocated them, the stack trace at the time of allocation, etc.

What I can't find is the address of the block that causes the problem. For example: if I leave off a `free` then valgrind gives me this output:

```
==94998== 56 (24 direct, 32 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 46 of 109
==94998==    at 0x1000A5E6B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:302)
==94998==    by 0x1000ED43D: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib)
... more deleted ...
```

The block in question here has type `unsigned long * p`. Now, `p` has a value, `0x1008ff2d0`. That address is *where the leak resides*, and I know it only because I set up the example & had it print the address. With the options listed above, valgrind does not tell me that `p` resides at `0x1008ff2d0`. It reports the locations of the functions involved; i.e., the address *where the memory leaked*.  These are two different things.

Knowing precisely which block causes the error can be helpful. I didn't find a way to display the block location when reading Section 4.2.8 of the manual, and I'm hoping I missed it. Does anyone know if this is possible?

**Note:** An earlier version of this question was marked as an "exact" duplicate and linked to a completely different question. It asked *how* to use `valgrind` for memory leaks *in general*, and the answers to the question specified the options I've already listed above. I know the basics of how to start valgrind and report detailed information; I am not asking that. I am asking whether there is another option, or mechanism, to obtain different information.

Comment: I've never used the option, but valgrind's core has a --read-var-info=<yes|no> [default: no] option.  The description is:
When enabled, Valgrind will read information about variable types and locations from DWARF3 debug info. This slows Valgrind startup significantly and makes it use significantly more memory, but for the tools that can take advantage of it (Memcheck, Helgrind, DRD) it can result in more precise error messages.
Here's the link to it.
http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#opt.read-var-info

Comment: Do you know why one has to go this route? Valgrind replaces malloc with its own custom malloc; that's how it knows the leaks in the first place. I'd imagine it knows the leaks because it knows their addresses. Why can't it just list the addresses without inspecting all that information?

(Voted you up, so I'm not being argumentative, just curious.)

Comment: To follow up: look at the first example at that link. It lists the address of for an uninitialized pointer error, despite the user not using that option (`Address 0x80497f7 is 7 bytes inside data symbol "global_i2"`). So valgrind knows the address of the pointer even without that option.

Comment: I see what you mean, but no, I don't know why you would have to go that route.  That first example would seem to imply that you shouldn't need it, so that may not help you anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have the list of blocks leaks, do the following:

- start your program under valgrind, with --vgdb-error=0 or with --vgdb-stop-at=startup
- then connect using gdb+vgdb.
- Then from gdb, you can put breakpoints and continue execution.
- when a breakpoint is reached, you do a memory leak search using e.g.
  (gdb)  monitor leak full reachable any
- You can then ask the details of the leaked blocks using e.g.
  (gdb)  monitor block_list ... give here loss record nr or range ...

Find more info in user manual, a.o.
http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver
and
http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.monitor-commands

Comment: Aiiieeee... I'm using clang + lldb. Any idea if it works that way?

Comment: (Also -- not a criticism of your answer, but --- if that's the only way, that seems like overkill. Valgrind does report addresses for some pointer errors; see comments above.)

Comment: clang compiled code should not be a problem. lldb + valgrind/vgdb sort of works (see https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=356174) but lldb is for sure missing some features to provide the same user experience as what you have with gdb + valgrind/vgdb

Comment: About overkill: no, not really. Several times, a suggestion to e.g. have --show-leaked-addresses was given. But this is not very useful : you cannot do much with just an address of a leaked block. With valgrind+gdb, you can investigate e.g. by looking at the block memory, by investigating the v-bits for uninit errors, by searching why something is possibly lost (as opposed to definitely lost) etc. So, in summary, have a 'simple' way to give the addresses of leaked blocks does not tell much.

Comment: Note also that valgrind reports the addresses for the errors where reporting address+offset helps to understand the error. For example, a jump due to uninit error is easier to understand because this tells e.g. which struct field causes the jump. But it is unclear how the address of a leaked block would help (without the interactivity offered by gdb to examine this block)

Comment: I disagree about whether it would be useful (for example, I *really* could have used it last week), and your answer leaves me worried about lldb (using OS X so not sure I have much choice) but it looks like the correct answer and the comments are helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @phd In my case, my project has a lot of available logging statements which record the object addresses. If Valgrind gives me the leaked address, I can find which object it is, in which context it was created, when its reference count increased but did not decrease within a block, etc.

Comment: Any idea of what are the resource implications of running a component under valgrind.

Comment: @prime depends on the tool and on your program. Can be between 5 and 100 times slower, and use between 2 to 5 times more memory.

Comment: @phd I'd also like to chime in that having the address of the leaked block can be helpful. With detailed tracing/logging statements, it can help to narrow down the source of the leak. For example, I can associate the address of the leaked block with an object ID. I can then do detailed logging of operations on that object.

Comment: To have a less verbose output and mention only the definitely leaked locations I'd suggest to use `monitor leak full definiteleak any`